# What is a healthy seasoning powder for vegetarians?

Tags: health

Normally, I use mushroom powder, but now it is out of stock in my place (New Zealand). The alternative to me is MSG or other artificial seasoning powder but I know they are not good for my health.
Is there any way to sort the problem regarding seasoning powder out?

Comment: why don't you use separate spices, or make a custom mix? ... if you are asking about which one to buy, then that is a shopping question, and is off topic

Comment: Regarding the mention of MSG, a relevant Q&A from Skeptics.SE: [Is monosodium glutamate (MSG) bad for you?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4270/15139) And from Cooking.SE: [Is MSG necessary or what to replace it with?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6109/95319)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually just go to the spices sections at the supermarket; and pick out different flavours I like and then mix them up. Smoked Paprika is a game changer sometimes. Try youtube vegan mixes for different foods.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your answer.  I agree.  My family don't even like hot spices but we still use mixed herbs, paprika, sage, rosemary, tomato puree, different things are nice in different dishes.  Mushroom powder is one I don't think I've encountered myself, might try it if I see any in the shops, it sounds useful - I like mushrooms.

Comment: I love mushrooms as well. Another thing i prefer is garlic salt (the one with 10% garlic and 90% salt), i just use that instead of salt if im making a quick meal. U can make custom mixes and just add sugar that the end so the taste is according to your level of spiciness.

Comment: Also nutritional yeast is good for adding a cheesy note, in particular to savory dishes

Answer (score 3):

### Taco Seasoning is Healthy

**I grind up:**

- 2.0Tbs Paprika
- 2.0Tsp Oregano
- 1.5Tsp Cumin
- 1.5Tsp Garlic Powder
- 1.0Tsp Coriander
- 0.5Tsp Cayenne Pepper
- 0.25Tsp Onion Powder
- 0.25Tsp Cinnamon
- a little salt

I heat it in the oven just long enough to make sure it is dry.

And put it on almost anything that is too bland. It does not take too much to do the job.

No MSG required.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I'm allowed to mention any brands here, but I really like [Deliciou](https://www.deliciou.com/).

It is Australian brand and they ship worldwide, so I guess it would be easy for you to order.
They are 100% vegan and the ingredients seem to be good as well.

In general, you can make your own spices by mixing basic ingredients. There are many recipes on internet or in any proper vegan cookbooks.
Your question is very generic, so I would say just find the mix that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to make my own custom mixes of spices, and like you, I am very selective about packaged seasoning mixes, avoiding too many artificial ingredients, and ones that are mostly just salt.  Its also easy to burn a lot of money getting fancy natural seasoning from upmarket stores like Farro or Huckleberry, so I try to avoid that too.

Main flavourings I tend to use are **Cajun, smoked paprika, hot curry powder, garam masala, garlic powder**.

Some good general seasonings that work on their own are natural non-msg stock powders (e.g. **Rapunzel** Organic Vegetable Bouillon Broth Powder), as well as **Massel reduced salt stock cubes** which have a solid umami flavour (the Massel "chicken" and "beef" cubes are also 100% vegetarian I believe).  I cook lentils with a massel cube, and even meat eaters complement the "meaty" savoury flavour.  **Yeast flakes** work fairly well as a seasoning too.

Also, if you are in Auckland, check out the Bulk Food Savings store in Mt Eden.

Answer (score 0):

As an off-the-shelf solution, or an inspiration to make your own, Schwartz Season All , in its [low salt version](https://www.schwartz.co.uk/products/seasonings-and-blends/ingredient-led/reduced-salt-season-all) contains

*Dried Onion, Garlic Granules, Dried Green and Red Bell Peppers, Ground Coriander Seed, Dried Glucose Syrup, Black Pepper, Cumin, Parsley, Savory, Dried Lemon Peel, Coriander Leaf, Oregano, Bay Leaves, Nutmeg, Ground Celery Seed, Acid (Citric Acid)*.

Dried onion flakes, if you can get them, are useful on their own.